# How to sort two arraylists according to their size into a new arraylist

Tags: java

I have two objects each with an id and a list.I would like to have a third arraylist sorting this object according to the list size.and still have the correaponding id along with the list

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach:

1. Create a [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which can compare two of the "id/list pairs" -- in this case, we compare the list sizes of the list component.
2. Create an [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of these "id/list pairs".
3. Use the [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method to sort the `ArrayList`, according to the `Comparator`.

If I understand correctly, there is a id/list pair. Here's one I made:

```
class IdListPair {
  int id;
  List<?> list;

  IdListPair(int id, List<?> list) {
    this.id = id;
    this.list = list;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "id: " + id + "; list: " + list;
  }
}
```

The `IdListPair` provides a constructor to create the id/list pair, and a `toString` method which will be used later to show the results of the sort.

Then, we'll have a section that creates an `ArrayList`, and sorts the list, using a `Comparator`:

```
List<IdListPair> pairList = new ArrayList<IdListPair>();
pairList.add(new IdListPair(0, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
pairList.add(new IdListPair(1, Arrays.asList(1)));
pairList.add(new IdListPair(2, Arrays.asList(1, 2)));

System.out.println("Before: " + pairList);

Collections.sort(pairList, new Comparator<IdListPair>() {
  public int compare(IdListPair o1, IdListPair o2) {
    return o1.list.size() - o2.list.size();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return false;
  }
});

System.out.println("After: " + pairList);
```

At first, an `ArrayList` was created with `IdListPair` that has lists of differing lengths.

Then, the [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method performs a sort according to the rules provided by the [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)). A class implementing `Comparator` needs to provide the [`compare`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) and [`equals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) methods.

Here, a `Comparator` was made so it will compare the [`size`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) of the `list` that each `IdListPair` object contains in the [`compare`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) method. The `equals` method is a dummy method as it isn't used here.

Most of the effort is going to come in writing the correct `compare` method, so the sorter of `Collections.sort` can correctly sort the list.

The results were as follows:

```
Before: [id: 0; list: [1, 2, 3], id: 1; list: [1], id: 2; list: [1, 2]]
After: [id: 1; list: [1], id: 2; list: [1, 2], id: 0; list: [1, 2, 3]]
```